# How do I enter the rupee sign?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I just found out in settings that elementary OS has an option to add the rupee symbol as an additional symbol on the number four key as seen in the below screenshot, but how do I enter that symbol?

[image: The rupee symbol four option in the settings window]

I've restarted my computer after toggling the setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have enabled that setting you can press

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

to create a ₹

Just tested it myself, you do not need to restart your computer or even exit the settings window. It just works.

But I do agree that it is a bit assuming to just call the setting "Rupee on 4". Although it is rather intuitive on a Scandinavian keyboard-layout like mine, it might not be on some kind of keyboards I guess.

Comment: The reason a was a bit of a second setting over here [Setting](http://i.imgur.com/rbavNA0.png?1)

Comment: I have removed the last part of your answer, asking why `Ctrl+Alt` does not work on elementary, please feel free to ask a new question about it.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt is not equivalent to AltGr because that's a hack that was done in Windows because the system didn't have a notion of an AltGr key, so they shoehorned it somehow. It causes a lot of conflicts between typing ordinary characters and application shortcuts.